# Trying to use __VA_ARGS__ in macro C++20

Tags: c++

I can't wrap my head around this problem. I'm trying to use Variadic arguments in a macro, I got it to work in C++11 with the following code:

```
#define INFO(format,args...)                                   \
{                                                              \   
    LOG_SEPERATOR;                                             \
    std::cout << "FILE: " << __FILE__ << "\n";                 \
    std::cout << "LINE: " << __LINE__ << "\n";                 \
    std::cout << "FUNCTION: "<< __func__ << "\n";              \
    std::cout << "INFO: \n";                                   \
    ConsoleLog(format,args);                                      \
    LOG_SEPERATOR;                                             \
}                              

                            \
```

But in C++20 I cannot use:

```
#define INFO(format,args...)
```

The compiler only accepts:

```
#define INFO(format,...)
```

Which means I can do this:

```
#define INFO(...) static int valuesArray[] = __VA_ARGS__
```

But I cannot do this:

```
#define INFO(format,...)
{\
 valuesArray[] = __VA_ARGS__ ; \
LOG_SEPERATOR; \
std::cout << "FILE: " << __FILE__ << "\n"; \
std::cout << "LINE: " << __LINE__ << "\n"; \
std::cout << "FUNCTION: " << __func__ << "\n"; \
std::cout << "INFO: \n"; \
ConsoleLog(format, valuesArray); \
LOG_SEPERATOR; \
}
```

I get E0969 - the identifier **VA_ARGS** can only appear in the replacement lists of variadic macros.

I looked for 2 days now, tried different solutions but I believe I'm way over my head here. I was trying to learn something new but now this just became a puzzle that frustrates me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well `valuesArray[] = ...` isn't valid to begin with.

Comment: As for your problem of logging, I suggest you look into template parameter packs and [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Comment: The macro at the end fails because you missed a backslash at the end of the first line. It will also fail for other reasons.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude corect I cropped the int valuesArray[] apologies.

Comment: And what happens if the arguments are *not* `int` values?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was testing at least with ints and found that:
#define INFO(...) static int valuesArray[] = __VA_ARGS__ was aceepted. I didn't account for not int values. Just trying first to access the _VA_ARGS__ outside the macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define INFO(format,args...)` was never standard C++. It is an extension supported by some compilers.

Since C++20 there is a standard replacement with `__VA_OPT__`:

```
#define INFO(format,...)                                   \
{                                                              \   
    LOG_SEPERATOR;                                             \
    std::cout << "FILE: " << __FILE__ << "\n";                 \
    std::cout << "LINE: " << __LINE__ << "\n";                 \
    std::cout << "FUNCTION: "<< __func__ << "\n";              \
    std::cout << "INFO: \n";                                   \
    ConsoleLog(format __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__);                                      \
    LOG_SEPERATOR;                                             \
}
```

There also is [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) in C++20 which allows implementing this common type of logging macro with a normal function.

Comment: actually the codes compile this way. I now have a different error on the call to `INFO()` but I don't think it's macro related. It appears it's a syntax error wiht  missing ')' before ',' I'll need to check this separtly I'll accept the answer! Thank you very much

Comment: @TiagoMatos `missing ')' before ','`: That shouldn't happen if you used `__VA_OPT__(,)` in the way I showed. There is no `,` before it.

Comment: I copied the line and added my namespaces:
`Proxima::Utility::Log::ConsoleLog(format __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); `
The compiler error is at the call for `INFO` and I'm calling it like this:
`  INFO("Teste %",1);` Now that I found __VA_OPT__ I'm trying some other literature.